# Adb invocation failed when trying to get android logs

Tags: android, macos, react-native

I'm trying to access the logs of my React Native application.

For that, I am running:

```
react-native log-android
```

However, I am getting this issue:

```
error: more than one device/emulator
adb invocation failed. Do you have adb in your PATH?
(node:24464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): undefined
(node:24464) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

`adb` is definitely in my path so that's not the problem.
I have only one Android Emulator open.

Any idea what else could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `adb devices`. Is there more than one? If so, turn of the extra device that you have connected. Sometimes your phone thats connected will count as a device. Also you want to have a `export PATH=$PATH:{YOURANDROIDTOOLS}` (something like /Users/{USER}/Library/Android/sdk/tools 
 or /Users/{USER}/Applications/Genymotion.app if you are using genymotion) in your zshrc or profile